# Getting a DIV element from an external webpage using JavaScript only

Tags: javascript

I'm having a slight problem. I'm trying to make a script for Google Sheets (JavaScript), where I need to import a number from an external webpage. This number is an exchange rate between coins and represents the cost of the "foreign" coin, displayed in my local currency.

This number I'm trying to import is held in a DIV, not a table, that's my problem.

What I have is:

- "Unique URL". The exact URL to the page where the exchange rate is located (no login is required, the data is publicly available).
- "Unique class name". The div does not have an ID, but it does have a unique class name.

Does anyone know how to extract this DIV (and it's content) and load it into my Google Sheet? Once I have the .innerHTML, I can format the content into a number and load it into my Sheet.

I have a feeling that it's fairly straight forward, if I only knew...

Comment: far from straight forward I am afraid, you cannot execute JS on another website. You would need to grab the data on your server, parse the HTML (assuming the HTML contains the number and it isn't added via JavaScript after page load), then query your server for the information via AJAX. Running JavaScript on other people's site is known as Cross Site Scripting (XSS) and is something developers work hard (or should do) to ensure doesn't happen for security reasons.

Comment: Really @GrahamRitchie

If it was a table, it would have been pretty straight forward.

Comment: ignore me, I realise now this is Google Sheets where you can use import XML `=importxml("https://websiteURL", "//div[@class='the-class-name'][0]")` - something along those lines, apologies that was my mistake misreading the question.

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines, but I haven't gotten it to work with DIV elements, only tables  That is why I though it would be fairly straight forward. But I get a #ERROR! in the Google Sheet. And THAT is why I was thinking that perhaps I'd have to create a custom script to fetch the data, since apparently the IMPORTXML() does not work. I feel like I'm SO close...

Comment: the key is to find the correct index of the item, if there are multiple divs with that class name you need to find which number it is so `[0]` may be `[6]` if it is the 7th div on the page. If you inspect an element, right click it in "elements" in the console you get copy > Copy XPath. Use that. You may need "Copy full Xpath" but that will not use classes, not sure, try both.

Comment: You can also use `*[@class='the-class-name'][0]`, `div` might not be valid in this context. With the `*` meaning any element.

Comment: There are only 2 elements with that class name and it's the last one of those, so it'll be the [1] element. I suppose it's not 100% unique then, but close enough.

Comment: give it a try with the `*` version, I would imagine that works and with the `[1]` index as you say.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie; I'm looking into it  Thx for the help. But I suppose I'll have to come back here though 